# error function and Meijer-G function

Tags: integration, special-functions

I am just wondering if there is any relation between the complementary error function Q-function and the Meijer-G function?

Comment: It can be represented in terms of MeijerG fuction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some relations for $\mathrm{erfc}$ and thus via simple substitution for $Q$ on the Wolfram function size, see 
http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Erfc/26/02/01/.

Comment: thanks a lot, but can we say, following the last identity in this link, that erfc(z)=G(z^2|...)?

Comment: Only for $z>0$ if you can trust Wolfram Alpha, enter  **Erfc[z] - (1/Sqrt[Pi]) MeijerG[{{},{1}}, {{0, 1/2}, {}}, z^2]**

Answer (score 2):

It can have the following representation

> $$\rm erfc (x)= 1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}{ 
> G^{1, 1}_{1, 2}\left({x}^{2}\, \Big\vert\,^{1}_{\frac{1}{2}, 0}\right)}.$$